# How to handle necessary duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me out with this conundrum. What would be the best practice to overcome the following situation. Consider the following database:

`ID | Name | HIREDATE | TERMDATE`

`01 | John | 01/01/14 | 07/01/14`

So, john here, as you can see left the company back in july 1st. He is however re-hired at a later date (Say, I dunno, 2/1/15). What would the community do?

a) Duplicate his entry and asign him an entirely different ID? -Possible cons: Might skew statistics when calculating things such as attrition, new hires, etc etc.

b) Add a new column for rehires despite it being a rare occurence and might go largely unused. -Possible cons: Might collide with other functions within the program such as searching for current employees unless checked.

c) Remove term date: out of the question. Statistics need to show all that were hired and termed at any given time and that would render the calculations innacurate.

d) Other: _________ <

I am leaning with option "a". I think there might be a way to adjust for calculations to reflect that there were rehires when calculating attrition and growth. What does the community think?

Comment: Create separate tables for "employee" and "employment period".

Comment: As DCoder said, the best practice is to create two different tables - one for the employees, where the employees are unique, and one for the periods. The relation is one to many.

Comment: Wouldn't separate tables end up in a join which would be slower than just allowing multiple rows with different employment periods?

Answer (score 1):

Of the 3 solutions you've posted, option a is the most viable. As you mention, the biggest drawback of option a is that you lose historical data that may be valuable in the long term.

I agree with your assessments of 'b' and 'c' and can't really think of a scenario where those would be optimal.

Personally, in almost all cases I would go with an "option d" except when I don't care about historical data for some reason.  Specifically, I would have a secondary table that stored various pieces of meta data for a employee.  This table would have a form similar to

```
META_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | KEY | VALUE
```

In this way, you could have an arbitrary number of hire and termination date (as well as any other meta data that you need to add in the future, e.g. `PROMOTION_DATE`).  Specific to your example:

```
META_ID | EMPLOYEE_ID | KEY    | VALUE
1         1             hired    01/01/14
2         1             termed   07/01/14
3         1             hired    02/01/15
```

You could do queries with `JOINS` to get the data that you are specifically interested and could have an unlimited number employee events.  You would always be able to select the last event in a given set of keys.

Comment: Oh this is a fantastic idea! I hadn't even thought of that! With this new table I can add additional info such as promotions like you mentioned as well as lateral moves within the company (switching departments) etc etc.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from trying to solve two different problems with the same table: representing current employees, and representing the employment history. Typically these data are needed for totally different purposes, and the data being stored may have to be different due to data protection laws.

Have one table for current employees and another for historical data.